# Metric Space and Symmetric Difference

Tags: metric-spaces, set-theory

Let $E$ a set and $X,Y$ subsets of $E$. We can define a metric on the subsets of $E$ with : $d(X,Y)=Card(X \Delta Y)$. I already show that $d$ is a metric but I need to show that we have $d(X,Y)+d(Y,Z)=d(X,Z)$ if and only if $X \cap Z \subset Y \subset X \cup Z$.

I started showing Card($X \Delta Y$)=Card($X$)+Card($Y$) if and only if $X\cap Y = \varnothing$.

How to show that equivalence ? Is that equivalence related to convexity ?

Thanks !

Comment: Under the condition $X \cap Z \subset Y \subset X \cup Z$ show that $X\Delta Z$ is the disjoint union of $X\Delta Y$ and $Y\Delta Z$.

Comment: @geetha290krm We know that card($A\Delta B$)=Card($A$)+Card($B$) if and only if Card($A \cap B$) = $0$ (*). Then, $ d(X,Y)+d(Y,Z)=d(X,Z) \iff$ Card($X \Delta Y$)+Card($Y \Delta Z$) = Card($(X \Delta Y) \Delta (Y \Delta Z)$) $\iff$ $(X \Delta Y)\cap (Y \Delta Z) = \varnothing$ using (*)

Comment: @geetha290krm look at my last comment, but I don't understand how